# I get an error didFailLoadWithError message after posting a SFRestRequest in my app

Tags: soql, rest-api, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios

Below is the error message I get when trying to retrieve a list of products from Salesforce through a SOQL via the SFRestRequest, When I replace Product with Account in the query string  I get results.

```
request:didFailLoadWithError: Error Domain=com.salesforce.RestAPI.ErrorDomain Code=999 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.salesforce.RestAPI.ErrorDomain error 999.)" UserInfo=0x175afa00 {message=sObject type 'Product' is not supported., errorCode=INVALID_TYPE}
```

I wasn't aware of a limitation of what standard objects that could be worked with through SOQL and the RestAPI.
below is the syntax for my query:

```
    SFRestRequest *request = [[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] requestForQuery:@"SELECT Id, Name FROM Product"];
[[SFRestAPI sharedInstance] send:request delegate:self];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for the `Product2` sObject?

If you're on OS X, [SoqlXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/) is a great admin tool. You should familiarise yourself with the schemas in the orgs in which you are working. :P

Comment: Bingo! I will check that ...

Comment: Jonathan, thanks for your answer, I replaced Product with Product2 and it worked like a dream AND I checked out that tool SOQLXplorer, it is just what I have been looking for - much appreciated! (Yes, I do familiarise myself with everyschema in every org I work in :P  )

Answer (score 1):

you are receiving error in response, there can be two possible reasons for this:

- You are querying a **production** instance of salesforce organization
- Or your logged in user profile don't have permission enabled for `Product` sObject or `Product` is not setup for organization.

Comment: great, I've checked the user and they are a System Admin, also they are logging into the production instance, but this is a fundamental prerequisite or did I read your answer incorrectly?

Comment: Thats default behaviour and basically salesforce is against accessing sObjects data from API. Production environment don't allow development. You have to do this with sandbox or developer. @Bartley

Comment: I'm at a loss here, do you have any idea how come I can get the data from the Accounts object?

Comment: I found a Salesforce document defining sObjects. apparently Rest API request to Product (and Pricebook for that matter) get refused. One should use Product2 or Pricebook2 instead. I will try this. These sObjects  (along with many other sObjects) are not available via Rest API requests via Force.com

Comment: `Product` is a classic table used with old API integrations (*very old API integrations*); no new code should ever use it. For compatibility purposes, you will always use `Product2` and `Pricebook2` instead.